# Problema al Instalar laravel 8 en docker con proxy

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, docker, composer

Buenos Dias a todos junto con saludarlos, les comento mi problema para instalar laravel 8 en mi PC (SO UBUNTU 21.04), ademas, ya instale Docker.
segun la documentacion de laravel ( https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-linux )

solo hay que ejecutar :

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

sin embargo, me arroja el siguiente problema :
[image: iTerminal error laravel]

antes de eso , hizo el pull de la imagen de docker pero al ejecutar la imagen

```
docker run --rm \
-v $(pwd):/opt \
-w /opt \
laravelsail/php80-composer:latest \
bash -c "laravel new example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium"
```

pasa el problema. ojala alguien me pueda ayudar con esto .. de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: será que no tienes permisos para el ejecutable de docker? ¿Te consta que el servicio docker está corriendo? Yo acabo de probar el curl que pusiste y me instaló todo

Comment: @ffflabs efectivamente Docker esta corriendo , es problema de configuracion de proxy, esa es la duda , no se si se podra modificar una imagen de docker , para configurar internamente los proxys correspondientes para que se ejecute.

Answer (score 0):

No se si es el problema que tienes, pero para configurar el proxy en docker hay al menos 2 [formas](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/).

- Editando/creando el archivo `~/.docker/config.json`
- Usando variables de entorno

En este último caso sería algo como:

```
docker run --rm \
-v $(pwd):/opt \
-w /opt \
-e HTTPS_PROXY="http://usuario:password@url_de_proxy:puerto/" \
laravelsail/php80-composer:latest \
bash -c "laravel new example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium"
```

Si necesitas el proxy para HTTP tienes que reemplazar o agregar la variabe `HTTP_PROXY` ( sin la "S" final ), lo que excluyas del proxy con `NO_PROXY` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final lo resolvi de la siguiente manera : si uno se mete a la url que da laravel (https://laravel.build/example-app), esto es solo un script en bash .. que es el siguiente :

```
    docker info > /dev/null 2>&1

# Ensure that Docker is running...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker is not running."

    exit 1
fi

docker run --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php80-composer:latest \
    bash -c "laravel new example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium"

cd example-app

CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LIGHT_CYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo ""

if sudo -n true 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo -e "${WHITE}Get started with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
else
    echo -e "${WHITE}Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.${NC}"
    echo ""
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo ""
    echo -e "${WHITE}Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
fi
```

Bueno , sobre este script, cree un archivo bash y le agregue el proxy y  quedo de esta forma :

```
#! /bin/sh
docker info > /dev/null 2>&1

# Ensure that Docker is running...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker is not running."

    exit 1
fi

docker run --rm \
    --env HTTP_PROXY="http://IPPROXY:PUERTOPROXY" \
    -v $(pwd):/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php80-composer:latest \
    bash -c "laravel new example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium"

cd example-app

CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LIGHT_CYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo ""

if sudo -n true 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo -e "${WHITE}Get started with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
else
    echo -e "${WHITE}Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.${NC}"
    echo ""
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo ""
    echo -e "${WHITE}Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
fi
```